# Zero subspace as solution space

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

Give an example of a $2\times3$ matrix $A$, if possible, such that the solution space of the linear system $Ax=0$ is:

a) the plane $\{(x,y,z)\mid 2x+3y-z=0\}$

b) the zero subspace

For a), I got $A=\pmatrix{1&0&2\\0&1&3}$ by obtaining the general solution of the equation. Is this correct?

As for b), I'm not sure how I should go about doing it. Can someone please explain this to me? I'm aware that this is probably a simple and basic concept, but I'm currently very lost and would really appreciate some help.

Comment: a) should be $A=\begin{pmatrix}2&3&-1\\0&0&0\end{pmatrix}$

Comment: @DHMO It has to be $2$ by $3$, so you want two rows.  Can just add a row of zeros, though.  OP, note that the $A$ you give for a) has rank $2$, so the solution space, by rank-nullity, will be $1$ dimensional, not a plane.

Comment: @Callus oh, I missed the $2 \times 3$ requirement. I've edited it now.

Comment: @Callus I didn't realize that. Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: @DHMO that seems a lot more straightforward than I thought. I will go check on my notes and attempt to correct my misconceptions. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part a) has been taken care of in the comments. Part b) is impossible because of the same rank-nullity theorem already mentioned there. Since $A$ is $2\times3$, its rank is at most $2$, therefore from
$$\operatorname{Rank}(A)+\operatorname{Null}(A)=3$$
we deduce that $\operatorname{Null}(A)$ is at least $1$. This means that the null-space of $A$, i.e. the space of solutions to $Ax=0$, is at least $1$-dimensional, and thus can't be the zero space.

Comment: Oh, I think I understand it now. Thank you!!